# HTML/CSS Image with link border not fully around image

Tags: html, css

I've got an home image that takes users back to the homescreen. I'm using Symfony 5.

Here's the HTML:

```
<a id="home-link" href="{{ path('app_mainRedirect') }}"> <img src="{{ asset('images/home-icon.png') }}" width="100" > </a>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#home-link { border-style:double;}
```

The image displays fine and the link works, but strangely the top of the border is displayed half way up the image. There's also a _ in the bottom right corner that I can't account for in the padding area. I'd be really grateful for any thoughts, may thanks in advance.

Edit: I've included an image.
[image]

Edit 2: as per suggestion, if I apply display: block, it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Please provide an image if you can't provide a working example. It's much more helpful than words.

Comment: If you apply `display: block` is it getting fixed?

Comment: `#home-link { border-style:double;width:100px; height:100px;}` does this fix your issue

Comment: if you do not want the border at all `#home-link { border: none;}` try this

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've edited as above to show what display: block does, interestingly it does have some effect and has got rid of the _ so I wonder if this is along the right tracks.
width:100px; height:100px; has no effect, which seems odd in itself.
You're right Paul, I don't really want the border, it's the _ I'm trying to get rid of but when I added the border I could see that there was something odd going on so wanted to work out what is going on there.
Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block;` to the anchor tag, it will show border properly around the image.

Also add `text-decoration: none;` to anchor to remove underline(_).

Comment: Thank you so much, it hadn't occurred to me that it's the underline of the link.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will get it to work as you expected

```
#home-link { border: none;}
```